# Random Images in Wp7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, random

I am making an application for windows phone in which i have to display random images whenever the new page is loaded...i am using the following code:-

```
private Random rand = new Random();
        private Image GetRandomImage(string PastScannerResults)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("/PastScanner/Results");
            int i = rand.Next(files.Length);
            return Image.FromFile(files[i]);
}
```

but not getting the results:-(
Please suggest something..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Directory.GetFiles is the syntax for XBOX.

In order to work with files on WP7 you need to use isolated storage.

Something *like* this should work:

```
IsolatedStorageFile userFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();  

var files = userFile.GetFileNames();

Random r = new Random();

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(files[r.next(0,files.count], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bi.SetSource(fileStream);
                this.img.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
                this.img.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
            }

this.img.Source = bi;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void image_random()

    {

        List<string> pics = new List<string>()
                   {
                           "Assets/1.jpg",
                           "Assets/2.jpg",
                           "Assets/3.jpg",
                           "Assets/4.jpg",
                           "Assets/5.jpg",
                           "Assets/6.jpg",
                           "Assets/7.jpg",
                           "Assets/8.jpg",
                           "Assets/9.jpg",
                           "Assets/10.jpg",
                           "Assets/11.jpg",
                           "Assets/12.jpg",
                           "Assets/13.jpg",
                           "Assets/14.jpg",
                           "Assets/15.jpg"
                           };

        Random rnd = new Random();
        ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
        brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pics[rnd.Next(0, 7)],
        UriKind.Relative));

        ImageBrush brush2 = new ImageBrush();
        brush2.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pics[rnd.Next(0, 7)],
        UriKind.Relative));


        img.Source = brush1.ImageSource;
        img1.Source = brush2.ImageSource;
    }
```